# Check box: Enable/Disable unchecked boxes when there is a number of checked ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently working on a kind of a multichoice form in my app (MVC5) and cannot figure out how can i disable unchecked boxes after there was a specific number of checked ones (Lets say that 3 was the max number, and 3 out of 5 were checked.. the other 2 should be disabled, and when one of the checked ones is unchecked, they should become enabled)
The web page  might have several forms/check lists with different constraints for each, so i'm looking for a dynamic type of work and would like to know if there is a way to do so or am i stuck with a static function for each check list.. Looking for help with the code either way.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Tried this with no success

```
@model IEnumerable<IMA_Elections.Models.Candidate>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Demo1";
}
<script src="~\Scripts\jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>window.onload = function() {
    alert( "שלום! הינך עומד\ת להתחיל בתהליך הבחירות. עלייך לבחור עפ''י ההנחיות המצויינות    תחת כל קטגוריה (ניתן גם לא לבחור). הצבעה נעימה" );

    }</script>
    <h1 class="text-center">ועד מרכזי <img src="~/Images/Logo.png"/></h1>

    <div class="row">

    <div style="float:right" class="col-md-3 right">
            <h2 class="text-center alert-success">ארק"ח-קהילה</h2>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right" class="col-md-2">
            <h4 class="text-center alert-success">נציגים</h4>
            <p style="text-align: center;" class="alert-info">בחר\י עד 3 נציגים</p>
            <form>
                 <div class="multiCheckBoxes">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <ul style="text-align: right;" class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.vote)
                        </ul>
                    }

                    <script src="~\Scripts\jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
                    <script>
                        $('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
                            var nightLifeLimit = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
                            if (nightLifeLimit == 3) {
                                $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
                                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                                        return;
                                    } else {
                                        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                                    }
                                });
                        } else {
                            $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
                                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right" class="col-md-2 right">
            <h4 class="text-center alert-success">מתמחים</h4>
            <p style="text-align: center; " class="alert-info">בחר\י מתמחה 1</p>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <ul style="text-align: right;" class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.vote)
            </ul>
        }
    </div>
    <div style="float:right" class="col-md-2 right">
        <h4 class="text-center alert-success">גמלאים</h4>
        <p style="text-align: center;" class="alert-info">בחר\י גמלאי 1</p>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <ul style="text-align: right;" class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.vote)
            </ul>
        }
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div style="float:right" class="col-md-3">
            <h2 class="text-center alert-success">ארק"ח-בתי"ח</h2>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right" class="col-md-2 right">
            <h4 class="text-center alert-success">נציגים</h4>
            <p style="text-align: center;" class="alert-info">בחר\י עד 4 נציגים</p>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <ul style="text-align: right;" class="text-center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.vote)
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
        <div style="float:right" class="col-md-2 right">
            <h4 class="text-center alert-success">מתמחים</h4>
            <p style="text-align: center; " class="alert-info">בחר\י מתמחה 1</p>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <ul style="text-align: right;" class="text-center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.vote)
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
        <div style="float:right" class="col-md-2 right">
            <h4 class="text-center alert-success">גמלאים</h4>
            <p style="text-align: center;" class="alert-info">בחר\י גמלאי 1</p>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <ul style="text-align: right;" class="text-center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.vote)
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="המשך" class="btn btn-success" />
        <input type="button" value="חזור" class="btn btn-danger" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what are the generated plain HTML of @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.vote)? Are they INPUT?

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) is a label, @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.vote) is a checkbox. none of them is input

Comment: you are not getting my point, I know they are labels and check box, but I need to see the output HTML of it. Do you have a live demo?

Comment: am I supposed to be able to see your HTML from the video?

Comment: I misunderstood you.. apologizes.   the input of the checkbox is: <input id="item_vote" name="item.vote" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.vote" type="hidden" value="false" />  The text is just a text with no input type

Comment: <ul style="text-align: right;" class="text-center">
                            פרופ&#39; פרת גדעון
                            <input id="item_vote" name="item.vote" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.vote" type="hidden" value="false" />
                        </ul>
the whole ul...

Comment: replace all the 'input' in my js with input[name="item.vote"]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in either pure Javascript or JQuery, here's a [WORKING DEMO using JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/2kGYW/)

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
    var nightLifeLimit = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
    if (nightLifeLimit == 3) {
        $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                return;
            } else {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        });
    }
});
```

Currently set limit to 3 which you can change at your will.

Comment: can this script be in an html? (Sorry, still a noob to js)

Comment: @Maratto yes of course, just remember to include jQuery library that's all.

Comment: and how can i use it multiple times in for several lists? or is it a different function for each form? if so, how do i bind each function to each form?

Comment: @Maratto you can specify different names for each set of input, like this input[name="firstset"]

Comment: @Maratto did you include jQuery library?

Comment: yes - <script src="~\Scripts\jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
and tried an onload alert that works

Comment: @Maratto what's your generated HTML? Are your options input? Obviously my demo works perfectly, and it is in plain HTML which would be compatible with any language.

Comment: My app is an MVC5 app, thus it's HTML with razor engine. don't get me wrong, i know it works perfectly and your help is more than appreciated! I just need a bit help with js since i don't have the time to learn js from scraps right now.

Comment: @Maratto yes I understand we all experience similar situation, please show me your generated code in between <ul> section. That might be the problem.

Comment: I'l just edit my main post with all the page's code - done, hope it will help (played a bit with the code if things will look messy there..)